# How to Pass parameter in table input?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have one job with two transformation in it.

1. Transformation  get list of data which is pass to another transformation. Here it execute for each row pass from first transformation.
2. In second transformation I have used

   "get row from result" -> "table input"

In "get row from result" there are five field but in table input i have to use only 2th position and 3th position field.

even if i try to give single param "?" its giving error

"
2017/06/29 15:11:02 - Get Data from table.0 - Error setting value #3 [String] on prepared statement
2017/06/29 15:11:02 - Get Data from table.0 - Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
"

My query is very simple 
select * from table where col1= ? and col2 = ?

How can I achieve this? error? Is my doing anything wrong ?

Comment: What is your SQl query? It looks like a SQL issue to me. " 2 is not between valid values of 1 and 1" which is right.

Comment: Even after passing correct params it through some other issue. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also give names to your parameters, so that your query become

> `select * from table where col1="${param2}" and col2="${param3}"`.

Don't forget to check the "Replace variable in script" checkbox, and to adapt the quotes to your sql dialect (ex: `'${param1}'` for SQL-Server).

Note the `param2` and `param3` must exists in the transformation's Settings/Parameters, without the `${...}` decoration and with values that don't break the SQL.

The values of the parameters can be set or changed in a previous transformation with a `Set variables` step (variables and parameters are synonymous in first approximation) and a scope at least `Valid in the parent job`.

Of course, if you insist in unnamed parameters for legacy purposes or any other reason, you are responsible to tell PDI that the first one is to be discarded, (eg `where (? is null or 0=0) and col1=? and col2=?`.

Comment: I don't quite get this. Do you mean that I need to create a transformation with "Get row from result" and then "set variable" with scope[valid in parent job]. Then what about the transformation that contains "table input"? Do I need to set anything for this transformation?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 5 fields arriving to the table input, you need to pass 5 parameters to your query, and in the right order. Also, each parameter will be used only once.

So, if you have 5 fields and only use 2 of them, the best way is to put a select values step between Get rows from result and Table input and let only the actual query parameters through.